# Calendar gets hidden inside accordian component

Tags: jsf, richfaces

The calendar component gets hidden behind the accordion item, no matter what z-index value you assign to the component, be it for accordion/calendar it simply won't budge, can some one help me on this. I'm using RichFaces 4.2.0.

Sample code:

```html
<h:form>
   <rich:accordion style="z-index:10;" id="acrdion" switchType="client">
        <rich:accordionItem id="acdItm" header="Overview:">
         <rich:calendar value="#{bean.date}" datePattern="dd/M/yy" 
                    id="Cal1" style="z-index:100;"/>
        </rich:accordionItem>
   </rich:accordion>
<h:form>
```

Comment: have you searched this bug on richfaces site?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I have raised a bug for this issue [RF-12349](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RF-12349)

Comment: when they solve the problem please post an answer and mark it so other people could resolve this problem too.

Comment: Sure @LuiggiMendoza I would be more then glad to help others out on a similar issue :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can workaround this issue by overriding the rf-ac-itm-cnt class as follows:

```
<h:outputStylesheet>
        .rf-ac-itm-cnt {
           overflow: visible;
        }
</h:outputStylesheet>
```